# Retrofit2: Use Body vs Query

Tags: android, web-services, http, retrofit2

I have a web-service method called `change`. I send `UpdateStatusRequest` objects to this web-service which defined as below:

```
public class UpdateStatusRequest {

    private String Status;

    public UpdateStatusRequest(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
}
```

When I use below API deceleration:

```
@POST("StatusUpdate")
Call<Status> change(@Query("Status") String status);
```

and then calling `statusApi.change(request.getStatus())`, it works well. It will call `http://server-url/StatusUpdate?Status=Ready`, when I pass `Ready` as status.

But using below declaration

```
@POST("StatusUpdate")
Call<Status> change(@Body UpdateStatusRequest status);
```

and then calling `statusApi.change(request)`, it will call `http://server-url/StatusUpdate` and sends `Status` in request body. This will lead to `404` status code with error prompt `Not Found`.

I want to know what's wrong with my second call (since I supposed `@Body` acts like several `@Query` parameters which bundled together in the same object)?

Comment: Does your service receive POST or GET?

Comment: `@Body` doesn't act like several `@Query` paramaters. These are two different ways of sending data, and it looks like the API you are using expects them to be in the latter format(`@Query`).

Comment: @diegoveloper It receives POST request.

Comment: @MateusGondim Can you explain more technically what's the difference of these two requests (what is the difference on information that server sees as requests).

Comment: @VSB added as an answer

Answer (score 3):

In Retrofit, 
`@Body` doesn't same as `@Query`.

- `@Body` – Sends Java objects as request body.
- `@Query`- Query parameter appended to the URL.`null` values are ignored.

But `@Field` is almost similar to `@Body` tag.

- `@Field` – Send data as form-urlencoded. The `@Field` parameter works only with a *POST*.

For Example:

```
@POST("StatusUpdate")
Call<Status> change(@Field("Status") String Status);
```

> But in your case, Your server is expecting the params to be passed in
>   the `URL(@Query)`.

Hope this explanation help.

Comment: Are there any ways to send all the fields of an object as separate parameters (like what `@Body` does with an object but as a bunch of query parameters)?

Comment: Yes, pass the bunch of query parameter you can use @Field. like (Call<String> register(@Field("userName") String userName, @Field("password") String password);)

Answer (score 1):

`@Body` doesn't act like several `@Query` parameters. These are two different ways of sending data in a request.

The differences are pretty much already described in your question. With `@Query`,it will append the URL with the query params you pass, as in `http://server-url/StatusUpdate?Status=Ready`. Instead, if you use `@Body`, the params will be added to the body request, so your URL will have no params, as in `http://server-url/StatusUpdate`, and your body request will be `Status=Ready`.

Based on the results you got, your server is expecting the params to be passed in the URL(`@Query`).